# SharePoint CAL included with MS Office license?

Tags: sharepoint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I heard that if you license certain version of MS Office, you get SharePoint (standard/enterprise?) CAL with it - does this make sense? Can you point me to a good source where this is explained (or denied?).

Comment: Contact MS Licensing at microsoft.com/licensing. They have a phone line that you can call to ask questions such as these.  Or, contact your vendor. Either should be able to explain the nuances of the software licensing.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has two  CALs generally now.  Core CAL should cover you but you can check this site for which one you might need as different versions of SharePoint are covered by a different CAL [MS CALs](http://www.microsoft.com/calsuites/en/us/products/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are thinking of is the [Office Professional Plus](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/professional-plus/) version of Microsoft Office 2010 that include a license of [SharePoint Workspace](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-workspace/microsoft-sharepoint-workspace-2010-FX101825648.aspx)

As far as I know there are no licenses of just MS Office 2010 that include a SharePoint CAL with it.  These would be included in the CAL suites (ie. CoreCAL and Enterprise CAL Suite), but not just for the standalone Office.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [Microsoft Professional Desktop Platform](https://partner.microsoft.com/global/40111206) license which allows you to run Office Professional Plus 2010 &  Windows 7 on your desktop, and you also get CAL's for SharePoint Server 2010 Standard, Exchange 2010 Standard and Windows Server 2008 R2 amongst other things. But I think these are usually only available to Enteprise grade customers who are buying a couple of hundred or more.